# Spring data JPA / SQL: Filter JOIN tables and show main table even if join was unsuccessful

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables:

```
 -------         ----------
|  User |       |   Order  |
|-------|       |----------|
|  id   |       |    id    |
|-------|       |----------|
|  name |       |  user_id |
 -------        |----------| 
                |start_time|
                 ----------
```

Lets say, i have records:

```
User {id: 1, name: "Sam"};
User {id: 2, name: "Andrew"};

Order {id:1, user_id: 1, start_time: '2020-00-00 00:00:00'}
Order {id:2, user_id: 1, start_time: '2021-00-00 00:00:00'}
Order {id:3, user_id: 1, start_time: '2022-00-00 00:00:00'}
```

How can i run posgre sql select, to get User in any case, even if order does not exists?
Like:

```
SELECT u.*, o.start_time FROM User u
INNER JOIN Order o on o.user_id = u.id AND o.start_time = '2030-00-00 00:00:00'

where u.name = 'Sam'
```

So, basically, i would like to get user in any case. And filter childs (joined table)

In the Spring Data Jpa terms, i would like to recieve user in any case, if user exist in DB and i would like to filter his / her orders by my sql query.

If I would try to get User with his / her filtered Orders, which do not exist, I wouln't recieve user from my query

Java code, domain object:

```
//Entity, Geter, Setter, equalsAndHashCode
class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Unique
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Orders> orders;
}

class Order {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
  private User user;

  private OffsetDateTime startTime;
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    

  @Query(to be done)
  Optional<User> findByUserNameWithFilteredOrders(@Param("userName") String userName,
                                                 @Param("startTime") OffsetDateTime startTime);
  
}
```

JTYF: I am interested only in custom queries, doing findBy... and generating query is not interesting for me, because i have more complicated case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the native query should be a left join instead of an inner join.

```
SELECT u.*, 
       o.start_time 
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN Order o ON o.user_id = u.id 
WHERE (o.start_time = '2030-00-00 00:00:00' or o.user_id = NULL)
```

This should give you all users regardless of their participation in the relation Order.

Comment: ```SELECT u.*, 
       o.start_time 
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN Order o ON o.user_id = u.id 
WHERE (o.start_time = '2030-00-00 00:00:00' or o.user_id = NULL)```  in this case i am recieving null, nothing is found

Comment: That's because the relational operators like `=`, `<`, etc. return `UNKNOWN` when one of the operands is `NULL`, which essentially means `FALSE`. If you want to check if something is null or not, you will have to use the `IS NULL` predicate i.e. `o.user_id is null`